# How to obtain full stack trace after exception from function passed as parameter?

Tags: python

I have wrapper function, that takes other function as parameter, catches an exception and does something with it:

```
    def exceptionCatchingWrapper(funcToCall,destForException,*args,**kwargs):
    try:
        r=funcToCall(*args,**kwargs)
    except:
        destForException["exc_info"]=sys.exc_info()
    else:
        return r
```

I realized that when an exception is caught, the stack trace taken from `sys.exc_info()` contains only information about `exceptionCatchingWrapper()` itself and nothing deeper. Is it possible and how to obtain full stack trace after such call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import traceback

def a(x):
    b(x)

def b(x):
    x/0

d = {}
exceptionCatchingWrapper(a, d, 10)
```

Traceback is stored in the dictionary:

```
>>> traceback.print_tb(d['exc_info'][2]
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in exceptionCatchingWrapper
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in a
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in b

>>> traceback.print_exception(d['exc_info'][0],d['exc_info'][1],d['exc_info'][2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in exceptionCatchingWrapper
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in a
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in b
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

More information in the [traceback module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#module-traceback).

Comment: Shame on me. Everything is OK

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need but these might be a way you can print the traceback:

```
import traceback
try:
    s += 1 #this doesnt exist yet
except:
    a = traceback.format_exc()
    print a
```

-or-

```
import traceback, sys

def DummyFunc2():
    s += 1 #this doesnt exist yet
def DummyFunc1():
    DummyFunc2()

try:
    DummyFunc1()
except:
    _, err, tb = sys.exc_info()
    tb_lines = traceback.extract_tb(tb)
    for idx, trace in  enumerate( traceback.format_list(tb_lines) ):
        print "[INDEX %d]\n%s" % (idx,trace)
    print err
```

output:

```
>>> 
[INDEX 0]
  File "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/xy/printtrace.py", line 9, in <module>
    DummyFunc1()

[INDEX 1]
  File "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/xy/printtrace.py", line 6, in DummyFunc1
    DummyFunc2()

[INDEX 2]
  File "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/xy/printtrace.py", line 4, in DummyFunc2
    s += 1 #this doesnt exist yet

local variable 's' referenced before assignment
>>>
```